# ¿Qué hace "palabra.split(" ")" en Python?

Tags: python, split

Dada la siguiente función no entiendo la línea:

```
ala = palabra.split(" ")
```

Pertenece a este código:

```
def reverse(palabra):
p = ""
ala = palabra.split(" ")   # <--- lo que no entiendo
for word in ala[::-1]:
    p += word
    p += " "
return p

print(reverse("La lluvia en Sevilla"))
```

Comment: Documentación: [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). Una observación, la concatenación de cadenas es muy ineficiente al ser objetos inmutables, una forma más eficiente de hacer lo mismo es usar el método `join` de las cadenas: `p = " ".join(reversed(palabra.split(" ")))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debes tener claro que primero obviamente la entrada es un ***str*** y también que la función split solo sirve para hacer listas, es una cadena si pones `palabras.split()` la cadena pasa automáticamente a una lista donde cada elemento esta separado por un espacio, es decir que la lista quedaría en tu código

```
 ["la", "lluvia","en","Sevilla" ]
```

Siempre recuerda que `split()` es para formar listas, si pones esta función estarás haciendo una lista y dentro de los () pones la forma de separación, puedes poner por ejemplo `split(",")` es decir que se separen con comas ó si pones `split()` por defecto python lo toma como espacio, separación por espacios.

Comment: Muchas gracias DDR! me quedo claro. Slds.

Answer (score 2):

Primero debes saber que `split()` hace que una cadena de texto (string) tenga una separación.

Por ejemplo:

```
nombreString = "hola mundo";
```

Al utilizar `split`:

```
nombre = nombreString.split();
```

obtendrás:

```
nombre = ["hola","mundo"]
```

Comment: no entiendo qué quieres decir con _hace que una cadena de texto tenga una separación_. Lo que hace `split()` es cortar una cadena en trozos, que acumula en una lista. Luego ya no tenemos una cadena, sino una lista.